# IE9 + pushstate + refreshing

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, backbone.js, hashtag, pushstate

I am using backbone.js and pushstate. In IE9, it degrades to using the hashtag and AJAX requests work just fine. The issue I have is with refreshing the page. My links are in the following format:

/a_username/a_collection_id

in IE9 if I am on:

/me/collection1

and I click on the AJAX link:

/me/collection2

I get this:

/me/collection1#me/collection2

When I refresh the page however, because the server knows nothing after the hashtag, I am brought back to /me/collection1 instead of the intended /me/collection2.

What is a workaround for this problem in browsers that don't have pushstate?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check on initial page load and see if there is a hashtag and then do a redirection.  Something similar to this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if (window.location.hash){
        window.location.replace("...root url..." + window.location.hash);
    }
};
```

Not the cleanest solution as it will cause a redirect whenever someone lands on a link with a hashtag but it will give you the result you're looking for.